# Using PutsReq to test a post & response and getting 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token e in JSON at position'

Tags: json, angular, http, syntax-error

Working on an Angular app (golf handicap generator) and following along with a Pluralsight video to implement a form and using Http and he is using PutsReq as a way to just test the post and response.  When I follow everything I am getting the above syntax error but unsure why.  All I am trying to do is send 2 different numbers.  Here is my code

Service Component

```
  postUserRoundsForm(userRounds: UserHandicapRounds) : Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post("https://putsreq.com/ZmOvG1coGYa174oig3r1", userRounds);    
  }
```

Template Component

```
  onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    console.log('in onSubmit: ', form.valid)
    this.dataService.postUserRoundsForm(this.userHandicapRounds).subscribe({
      next: (v) => console.log('Donzo: ', v),
      error: (e) => console.log('Errorrr: ', e),
      complete: () => console.log('complete: sends NOTHING')
    })
  }
```

HTML

```
<form #handicapCalcForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(handicapCalcForm)">
```

I also checked the network tab in chrome and saw the payload is coming back with the correct data.  I also tried re-serving the app and a different browser and that didn't help either.

I'm fairly new to HTTP and trying to learn more about it but haven't been able to find a reason as to why this isn't working, I would think it should

Comment: Can you share what is the response returned from the API?

Comment: Isn't it just what I put up in the title of this question, i.e. SyntaxError etc...?

Comment: I mean does your API return what kind of response, JSON, XML? From the error in your title, it seems your API is not returning the response in JSON. Without further details, it is hard to help in debugging and providing the solution. That is why I request the response.

Comment: it returns JSON.  When I go into the network tab and look at the paylod it returns

{"eighteenHole_score":50,"nineHole_score":30}

Comment: I got the same problem as well, doing an angular forms course on pluralsight. In the responsebuilder I am doing the following: var parsedBody = JSON.parse(request.body); This seems to be the source of the problem. When testing in PostMan, I get the same error whenever I post json. Somehow it seems to have problems parsing json. I first thought it could be wrong content-type header, but setting that to application/json did not help. Did you figure this one out? I'm considering switching to a different service than putsreq...

Comment: In case it helps, I gave up on putsreq, as it seems to be a bug in their service that prevents handling of json in request body. I switched to pipedream.com instead, and it works fine.

Comment: That's helpful to know, I thought it was perhaps an issue with putrsreq.  Thanks for confirming!